# jquery css selector to addClass to divs with background image of

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on an advanced map application in Google Maps API V3. I'm using an array of lettered markers for the pins on the map (A-J). I've written some jQuery to grab add a different class to each div that contains the marker as a background image so that I can animate the markers. Here's the code I'm using to do this:

```
$('.markersHolder > div').each(function(){
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerA.png)'){
             $(this).addClass('marker0');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerB.png)'){
             $(this).addClass('marker1');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerC.png)'){
              $(this).addClass('marker2');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerD.png)'){
              $(this).addClass('marker3');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerE.png)'){
              $(this).addClass('marker4');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerF.png)'){
              $(this).addClass('marker5');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerG.png)'){
              $(this).addClass('marker6');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerH.png)'){
              $(this).addClass('marker7');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerI.png)'){
              $(this).addClass('marker8');
           }
           if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerJ.png)'){
              $(this).addClass('marker9');
              return false;
           }
         });
```

This works perfectly in Firefox but doesn't work in other browsers. Anyone have any clue how to get this to work in other browsers? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should find the "MarkerA" (etc.) portion of the url of the background-image and if it finds it, add the class using the character code of the capital letter to calculate your 1, 2, 3, etc. on your "marker" class (I have not tested it):

```
$('.markersHolder > div').each(function(){

   var mark = $(this).css('background-image').match(/Marker./);
   if(mark) {
     $(this).addClass("marker"+(mark[0].charCodeAt(mark[0].length-1)-65));
   }
});
```

Added this on edit:

If you match the class name to the image name as mcgrailm suggested in the comment to Pekka then it could be just:

```
$('.markersHolder > div').each(function(){
   var mark = $(this).css('background-image').match(/Marker./);
   if(mark) {
     $(this).addClass(mark[0]);
   }
});
```

Comment: Doh, beat me by a solid 10 minutes while i was fiddling with my regex string

Comment: Yeah, that took me a few minutes too :-)

Comment: This solution is PERFECT!!! Thanks guys!! I've really gotta learn that regex stuff. Where did you look that up at?

Comment: I've just been learning it by doing searches on the web for it. There is a lot of stuff out there for regex and it does take a while to digest (I would still consider myself somewhat of a novice at it).

Comment: I find [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) to be a good reference list when I don't remember what to use. But I'd recommend a tutorial to start with to get in the foundations :)

Answer (score 1):

I would have the browser `alert()` the `$(this).css('background-image')` - my bet is different browsers return this in different ways, e.g. quoted:

```
 'url("http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_MarkerJ.png")'
```

it could be that you'll have to *search* for the image name in the URL string rather than making an exact comparison.

Comment: +1 Searching rather than doing an exact match sounds like a more robust solution. However, I still think there is too much code duplication going on here.

Comment: @Anurag it definitely is: This would be best in an array.

Comment: ok. I'm a bit new to jQuery, I'd like to be able to just search for the letter at the end of the image name as you quoted above (J.png)? How would I write this?

Comment: how would I put this into an array?

Comment: i would suggest using a class named in the same maner as your image is named

Answer (score 0):

If it's just this repetitive code, you should be able to use a regex

```
$(".markersHolder > div").each( function() {
        var r = new RegExp("^url\\(.{0,1}http://www.axtsweapons.com/gmarkers/red_Marker([A-Z]).png.{0,1}\\)");
        var s = $(this).css('background-image');
        var x = s.match(r);
        if (x) {
            var charToInt = x[1].charCodeAt(0) - 65;
            $(this).addClass('marker' + charToInt);
        }
});
```

It extracts the letter after `red_marker` in the image url and converts it to the appropriate number to find the correct class. You may want to narrow down the `.{0,1}` part, as `.` may be too broad (i imagine whitespace, `'` and `"` should be the only cases)